# How do I state this correctly and with the correct intention in Russian?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

I found an old friend on an social media website, and I want to contact them.

I want to somehow say something like:

> "You're here, too? Interesting....."

But I want to say this in a nice way. I'm already not happy with the English version. I somehow want to express that I was surprised to see them here again and I want to state that I'm suprised IN A GOOD WAY, and that this is interesting. In other words, I don't want to come across negatively and possibly make them feel bad. So it's important that it have a positive, friendly sound. Perhaps a funny version would also be ok. I'm not a pro at Russian, and this is way too hard for me. My attempt (most likely wrong) would go something like this:

> дю Ош иерархи? круто :-)

EDIT:
I'd further like to add that I think that this person should not have any problem getting in touch with other people (high social proof well looking). Their profile states that he's looking to make new friends. I also want to imply that I think he should have no problem meeting people in the big city where he lives. Like a compliment of sorts - something nice so that he'll take my comment in the right spirit and be more likely to respond.
English:

> You should have no problem meeting people here in xxxxx! :-)

I don't like that because I'm afraid it might come across as sarcastic. I don't want to risk him taking it as sarcasm! So how can I express this in Russian without the risk of coming off as sarcastic? My basic Russian is way too bad. *please help*

Comment: Your ‘_дю Ош иерархи? круто_’ is definitely the funniest thing I’ve seen in a week. :-D But I can’t understand a word except of _круто_.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov Damn, maybe you could help me out, would be very nice!

Comment: What about и ты здесь? прохладно!

Comment: The proposed variants translated from Russian would be "Are du Osh hierarchs?" and "And you here too? It's cold!"

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov: Obviously he entered "Bist du auch hier Archie? (Are you also here, Archie?) in a translation site, and it transcribed "du" and "auch" as дю and ош, and "hier Archie" as иерархи. hahahahahahahaha

Answer (score 4):

Sometime simplicity is best - О! Какой приятный сюрприз! Рад видеть... By the way, slang meaning of *cool* is **opposite** of Russian *прохладно* (прохладно means lukewarm; not cool)

Answer (score 1):

«и ты здесь? Здорово!»

«о, ты тоже тут? Клёво!»